# Trigger not working all the time

Tags: mysql, triggers

Here's my trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `data_temp_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `data_temp`
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN

    DECLARE nextInc INT DEFAULT 0;  // I have try to define AS a varchar...
    DECLARE idrad varchar(75);
    DECLARE idio_bat varchar(75);
    DECLARE UniqueID varchar(75);
    DECLARE ServerID varchar(75);

    SELECT IDRadio INTO idrad FROM radio WHERE radio.XB_SL=NEW.XB_SL AND Actif=1 LIMIT 1;
    SELECT ID_IO INTO idio_bat FROM io WHERE io.IDRadio=idrad AND NoIO=1 AND Actif=1 LIMIT 1;

    SELECT IDServerInfo INTO ServerID FROM serverinfo WHERE Actif=1;

    SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT INTO nextInc FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'io_data' AND table_schema = DATABASE( ) ;

    SET UniqueID = CONCAT(ServerID,'-',nextInc);

    IF NEW.Battery IS NOT NULL AND idio_bat IS NOT NULL AND idio_bat != 0 THEN 
        UPDATE io_data SET ValueRead=1, DateModification=now() WHERE  ID_IO=idio_bat AND ValueRead=0 AND Actif=1;
        INSERT INTO io_data (ID_IO_Data, ID_IO, ReadingValue, Timestamp) 
             VALUES (UniqueID, idio_bat, NEW.Battery, NEW.Timestamp);
    END IF;

END
```

Here's the insert query in data_temp (on which the trigger is set)

```
INSERT INTO data_temp (XB_SL, HType, Battery, Temperature, Value_1, Value_2, Value_3) VALUES ('1086507849', '2', 22, -23, -0.9, -4.6, -4.9);
```

Here's the io_data table structure :

```
ID_IO_Data  varchar(75)
No      int     AUTO_INCREMENT  
ID_IO       varchar(75) 
ReadingValue    decimal(5,2)
Timestamp   timestamp   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP       
ValueRead   int
```

I have 2 differents situations.

**The one which is working :** (the update in io_data and also the insert)

The IDServerInfo (defined as varchar 75) value is 230000-A8754126-8B0D-4D68-A20A-7F97EDE1CE43

So, every ID created is using this IDServerInfo concatenated with an autoincrement for the table (define as varchar 75).

When populating data in data_temp table with this IDServerInfo, everything works well.

**The way which IS NOT working :**

The only difference in the setup is that the IDServerInfo contains a letter for the first character (ex. **Z**23000-A8754126-8B0D-4D68-A20A-7F97EDE1CE43) (I've tried **Z**230000-A8754126-8B0D-4D68-A20A-7F97EDE1CE43 and not working too)

Anyone can help? Do you have enough informations to be able to understand what I'm doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

I've tried with multiple different IDServerInfo

All of those one **aren't working**

Z230000-

Z23000-

ZZZZZZZ-

ZZZ111-

A123456-

---

Those one **work**!

230000

230000Z

1ZZZZZZ

111ZZZ

So if the 1st character is a letter, it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why exactly, but I found the error and it was in the if condition :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `data_temp_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `data_temp`
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN

DECLARE nextInc INT DEFAULT 0;  // I have try to define AS a varchar...
DECLARE idrad varchar(75);
DECLARE idio_bat varchar(75);
DECLARE UniqueID varchar(75);
DECLARE ServerID varchar(75);

SELECT IDRadio INTO idrad FROM radio WHERE radio.XB_SL=NEW.XB_SL AND Actif=1 LIMIT 1;
SELECT ID_IO INTO idio_bat FROM io WHERE io.IDRadio=idrad AND NoIO=1 AND Actif=1 LIMIT 1;

SELECT IDServerInfo INTO ServerID FROM serverinfo WHERE Actif=1;

SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT INTO nextInc FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'io_data' AND table_schema = DATABASE( ) ;

SET UniqueID = CONCAT(ServerID,'-',nextInc);

IF NEW.Battery IS NOT NULL AND idio_bat IS NOT NULL AND idio_bat != 0 THEN 
    UPDATE io_data SET ValueRead=1, DateModification=now() WHERE  ID_IO=idio_bat AND ValueRead=0 AND Actif=1;
    INSERT INTO io_data (ID_IO_Data, ID_IO, ReadingValue, Timestamp) 
         VALUES (UniqueID, idio_bat, NEW.Battery, NEW.Timestamp);
END IF;
```

END

The 0 in that condition : idio_bat != 0 must be between quote =>

```
IF NEW.Battery IS NOT NULL AND idio_bat IS NOT NULL AND idio_bat != "0"
```